# Can I use two conjunctions in one sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

I learned that if I use two conjunctions in one sentence, I need at least three separated sentences.
(subject+verb **conjunction** subject+verb **conjunction** subject+verb.)

***For** the wages of sin is death, **but** the gift of God is eternal life in Christ Jesus our Lord.*

In this sentence, the two conjunctions 'for' and 'but' are used without main(or pivot??) sentence.

Then, why is this sentence grammatical?

Comment: "For" is not a conjunction here but a preposition meaning "because".

Comment: “Because ... , but ...” does not quite work. I feel that “For ...” is acting as a sort of demonstrative preposition in this quotation.